# Why does /\ss\$/ not match two spaces at the end of the line?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match two spaces at the end of a line with `/\ss\$/` against `word word` . What did I mess up in regex?

Comment: `\ss\$` is a whitespace, an `s`, and an escaped `$` sign. Sure you didn't mean `\s\s$`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is `\s`, so two spaces is `\s\s` (or `\s{2}`). `\ss` is `<space>s`. So try `/\s\s$/`. If you need to capture the two spaces, make it a capturing group: `/(\s{2})$/`.

See also: [this regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/tR0hN4/1).

Comment: it still returns no match.

Comment: See edit. Also, depending on how/where you use it (library, language), you may need to remove the `/` at the start and end. Also, did you remove the extra \ before `$`?